# Biblatex: Manually sorting one paper and its regarding corrigendum

Tags: biblatex

I have one paper, with a corresponding (distinctly published) corrigendum. However, I want the corrigendum to be listed directly after the original paper.

Here is a short MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=ext-authoryear,
sorting=nyt,maxbibnames=9,maxcitenames=2,uniquelist=false, backend=biber, 
doi=false,isbn=false,url=false,
uniquename=false, date=year, giveninits=true, dashed=false]
{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname2.bib}
@Article{Hansen2011,
  author  = {Hansen, Peter R. and Lunde, Asger and Nason, James M.},
  title   = {The Model Confidence Set},
  journal = {Econometrica},
  year    = {2011},
  volume  = {79},
  number  = {2},
  pages   = {453-497},
  url     = {https://EconPapers.repec.org/RePEc:ecm:emetrp:v:79:y:2011:i:2:p:453-497},
}

@Article{Hansen2011b,
  author  = {Hansen, Peter R. and Lunde, Asger and Nason, James M.},
  title   = {Corrigendum to “The Model Confidence Set”},
  journal = {Econometrica},
  year    = {2011},
  volume  = {79},
  number  = {2},
}

\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname2.bib} 

\begin{document}
\textcite{Hansen2011}
\textcite{Hansen2011b}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

I just want to change the sort order for the two papers. Otherwise, the paper that was first published should continue to be listed with the same authors. Maybe it helps to say that I quoted him text first the original paper and then the corrigendium

Comment: Another nice approach uses the `related` field to list both entries at once, https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/416504/35864

Comment: I think the approach by Coby Viner is much clearer, but maybe personal preference

Comment: Fair enough. The 'philosophies' behind the approaches are different. Coby Viner's solution prints the erratum as a second paper in the bibliography while the linked answer combines the paper and its erratum into one entry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest that you make use of the `sorttitle` BibLaTeX field (see pg. 30, within § 4.5.9 "Fine Tuning Sorting", of the [BibLaTeX manual](http://ctan.forsale.plus/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf)) for this purpose, as discussed in [a related answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/61535/134641).

Specifically, you can simply add `sorttitle = {The Model Confidence Set corrigendum}` to `Hansen2011b`, which will ensure that it is placed after `Hansen2011`.

You could alternatively use `sortyear` or `presort` in conjunction with other modifications, as [outlined](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/46879/134641) [elsewhere](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/131998/134641).

Comment: While `sortyear` would currently be an alternative, this can't be guaranteed in the future: https://github.com/plk/biber/issues/228. So `sorttitle` is safer, if a bit more awkward.

Comment: `presort` is not something I would use for this case and I don't see how it could help efficiently here.